# Tenho uma dúvida sobre este trecho de código - Scanf

Tags: c, scanf

Olá, gostaria de uma ajuda com este trecho de código, alguem poderia me explicar o que ele faz exatamente ?(Especialmente a parte %*1[\n])

```
scanf(%[^\n]%*1[\n], string);
```

Comment: Mr robot, isso se chama **Expressões regulares**, é uma forma de "formatação e validação" de input.
Não sei exatamente qual é a formatação no seu código, mas dê uma pesquisada para saber melhor.

Comment: @welington2632 neste caso **não** são expressões regulares, são códigos de formatação para a função scanf

Answer (score 2):

`%[^\n]`: lê uma cadeia de caracteres até encontrar um '\n' (final de linha).

`%*1[\n]`: este * logo após o % indica que o que for lido não será atribuído a nenhuma variável (no caso é para desprezar o ENTER).